# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser

Tags: android

mi codigo es este:
Manifest:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.providers.FileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
</application>
```

**Metodo para mandar foto:**

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(String name) {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile;
            photoFile = createImageFile(name);
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplication().getApplicationContext(),
                        "com.example.pc_intel.photo.provider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, TAKE_PICTURE);
            } else {
                Log.wtf("photoFile", "photoFile null");
            }
        } else {
            Log.wtf("TakePicture", "resolve acivity null");
        }
    }
```

**XML donde esta la el path**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="imagenesFotoA"/>
</paths>
```

Answer (score 0):

El package name de tu aplicación es:

```
 "com.example.pc_intel.photo.provider"
```

por lo tanto el permiso que debes asignar a tu Provider es:

```
android:authorities="com.example.pc_intel.photo.provider"
```

en lugar de :

```
android:authorities="${applicationId}.providers.FileProvider"
```